# Fatal Error in convert PPT to PNG in PHP

Tags: php, png, powerpoint

I want to convert PPT to PNG with PHP. I wrote the following piece of code to solve the problem:

```
$powerpnt = new COM("PowerPoint.Application") or die('could not create the powerpoint instance');
$powerpnt->Visible = True;

$strPath = realpath(basename(getenv($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])));

$FileName = "MyPP";

$powerpnt->Presentations->Open("D:\\MySlide.ppt"); /* This is line #16 */

$powerpnt->ActivePresentation->SaveAs($strPath."/".$FileName,17);

$powerpnt->Quit;
$powerpnt = null;
```

But I got the following Fatal error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2007<br/><b>Description:</b> PowerPoint could not open the file.' in C:\wamp\www\ppt2jpg\ppt2jpg.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\ppt2jpg\ppt2jpg.php(16): variant->Open('D:\MySlide.ppt') #1 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\ppt2jpg\ppt2jpg.php on line 16`

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the MySlide.ppt file does actually exist in D:\

Comment: I'd say the error is not related to PNG conversion. It happens one line earlier, when opening the PPT file.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd try to open the file with some other PHP function like `file_get_contents()`, just to make sure it's readable. Additionally, make sure the presentation belongs to a format that's supported by your system.

Comment: Try opening the file manually from within PPT.  That puts your code out of the picture.  If it still fails, it might be that the file's corrupt, in the wrong format for the extension, or that Windows is being cranky about letting you at files in the drive's root directory.

Comment: The problem should be that Powerpoint is not allowed to access the file via PHP application