# new COM("PowerPoint.Application") Doesn't work

Tags: php, png, powerpoint

I'm trying to convert slides on a ppt file to a PNG files, but something wrong with my code.

in a local test the script stuck at this line :

```
$ppApp = new COM("PowerPoint.Application") or die ("Unable to instantiate PowerPoint");
```

then show `"Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded";`

And when i go on my live server, the script work for the first time, but then it's show up an error

> "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not close ppt file 1251.pptx.'

I'm on a Windows server, and i think something wrong with the way i'm using ppt process.

Here is the Code :

```
$ppApp = new COM("PowerPoint.Application") or die ("Unable to instantiate PowerPoint");
    $ppApp->Visible = True;
    $strPath = realpath(basename(getenv($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])));
    $ppName = $jobQuery['id'].".pptx";
    $FileName = "MyPP";

    //*** Open Document ***//
    $ppApp->Presentations->Open(realpath($ppName));

    //*** Save Document ***//
    $p_opned =  $ppApp->ActivePresentation->SaveAs($strPath."/".$jobQuery['id']."_".$FileName,18);
    //$ppApp->ActivePresentation->SaveAs(realpath($FileName),17);
    $ppApp->Quit();
    $ppApp = NULL;
    unset($ppApp);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well firstly one thing to check is you max execution time, as it appears to be still set at the default 30 seconds. So try set_time_limit(0) at the top of your script. Please supply more of your code regarding your Exception problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just add the code. i all ready try to fix the max execution time. the issue is after execuiting the script for the 1st time the Process POWERPNT.EXE still running in the background.

Comment: Server side office document processing is not really recommended. Take a look at this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/EN-US

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be with your saving location or simply your file was not found, are you sure that the location you're trying to save to actually exists as from your code I'm not so sure?

```
$strPath = realpath(basename(getenv($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])));
```

**Should be:**

```
$strPath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
```

**Are you sure that this file actually exists in the location:**

```
$ppName = $jobQuery['id'].".pptx";
```

Check it with:

```
file_exists($ppName)
```

Look here for a similar question: [Fatal Error in convert PPT to PNG in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786379/fatal-error-in-convert-ppt-to-png-in-php)

**EDIT:**

Try the below, I think your $p_opned was keeping the reference open to your $ppApp object and hence your instance wasn't properly removed.

```
//*** Save Document ***//
$ppApp->ActivePresentation->SaveAs($strPath."/".$jobQuery['id']."_".$FileName,18);
```

**EDIT 2:**

As requested try wrapping the line you think is causing the exception (so assuming its this line):

```
try {
  //*** Save Document ***//
  $ppApp->ActivePresentation->SaveAs($strPath."/".$jobQuery['id']."_".$FileName,18);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception message: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Although looking again at your error message it refers to your original file you tried to open (1251.pptx) as you're trying to save the file with a different post fix (which it doesn't mention in the code).

You could try wrapping the Exception try / catch around the 'Open' script line if the above doesn't work, or perhaps you could try adding before you Quit:

```
$ppApp->ActivePresentation->Close();
```

If your error is because Powerpoint is still hanging around after the first instance call it must be because you still have a reference alive somewhere, so try checking ALL your code. If you still get an error you should include the FULL error message in your question and remove the Max execution error message from your question is this not actually a problem (I assume you don't still get the "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" message anymore?).

**Lastly you could always try a PowerPoint library:**

http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/

Comment: The file it's there, but maybe you're right. I mean if an error happened then the quit() function will not be executed. So how can i avoid error using try and catch in this situation? any idea?

Comment: Please see edited answer - perhaps your $p_opned = was keeping the Powerpoint instance open, might as well not have this as you don't seem to use the $p_opned var anyway?

Comment: I removed the $p_opned file and i still getting the error at the same line.there are any way check this line  with a try & catch? like if(error) do Quit() ?

Comment: Try absolute path for open and save.

Comment: Also try ->Open($filename,false,false,false);